# SOAP web services over HTTPS is not working

Tags: soap, nusoap, sugarcrm, soap-client

I am currently working in sugarcrm which has url in https. Soap is not working on https url, my code is running perfectly in http url . What are the changes that requires to run the same code in https mode?

i use this code. username, password and url is only for example for you people.

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap.php');
$client = new soapclient('https://www.sugarcrm.com/soap.php?wsdl',true);
$auth_array = array(
'user_auth' => array(
'user_name' => 'abc',
'password' => md5('abc'),
)
);

$login_results = $client->call('login',$auth_array);
echo $session_id = $login_results['id'];
$user_guid = $client->call('get_user_id',$session_id);
printf("\n".$auth_array['user_auth']['user_name'].' has a GUID of ' . $user_guid . "\n\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the $sugar_config site_url setting properly reflects the https URL. You can change this in the config.php file in the root of your SugarCRM install.

Comment: Thanks jmertic for replying, issue is that:                                my sugarcrm has url in https, which means its site_url in config.php will be in https, so where to change now?

Comment: So you are saying the site_url config.php setting has the https in it, right?